# What does the "struck last year" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

> On the campaign trail he promised to withdraw from an international accord, **"struck" last year** in Paris, to fight global warming. This week, as president-elect, Mr Trump said he has an “open mind” on the Paris deal and that there is “some connectivity” between human activity and climate change.

I've looked it up the dictionary but couldn't find anything that fit the meaning in the context. And I know it's the past tense and the past participle of "strike".

Comment: The term *strike a deal* is often used for *make a deal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[to strike](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strike)*** a deal or an agreement is an idiomatic expression that means to close a deal or reach an agreement;

> - [T] to reach or make an agreement:
>
>   - *Do you think the government should try to strike a deal with the terrorists?*

Cambridge Dictionary

- The international accord was struck (made) last year